# How ROCR package of R can be used to handle label (output) with just one class?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am using ROCR package of R to measure the performance of a model. A simple snippet of my code could be assumed as the following:

```
predic <- c(0.30, 0.59, 0.60, 0.71, 0.86)
label <- c(1,    1,    1,    1,     1)

pred <- ROCR::prediction(predic, label)
```

But unfortunately it sounds that I cannot use ROCR for label(output) with just one class and I received the following error:

```
Error in ROCR::prediction(predic, label) : 
  Number of classes is not equal to 2.
ROCR currently supports only evaluation of binary classification tasks.
```

Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Comment: What are you hoping to do with ROCR using a single class?

Comment: Analyze the result of one-class SVM model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're out of luck.  Even instantiating a 'Prediction' object
directly raises errors...

```
cutoffs = sort(c(Inf,sort(predic,decreasing=TRUE)))
len = length(cutoffs)
tp <- apply(outer(sort(predic),cutoffs,`<`),2,sum)
fn=

new("prediction", 
    predictions = predic,
    labels = label,
    cutoffs = ,
    tp = tp, #cases
    fn = len-tp-1,#cases
    fp = rep.int(0,len),#controls
    tn = rep.int(0,len),#controls 
    n.pos = length(predic),
    n.neg = 0,
    n.pos.pred = tp,
    n.neg.pred = len-tp-1)


#> Error in initialize(value, ...) : argument is missing, with no default
#> Calls: new -> initialize -> initialize
```